# Optional Field on base class but mandatory on child class in Django

Tags: django, django-models

i would like to know if its possible to have 2 classes (base=person and a child=user) where i have a property (email) nullable on base but it must be set for child class

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, )
    identification = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True) #<~~~~ Email can be null

    def __str__():
        return self.name

class User(Person):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=60, ) #<~~~~ Email CAN'T be null
```

If i leave it like this i get this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'email' in class 'User' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'Person'.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are doing [multi model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#multiple-inheritance), then the child creates a [OneToOne relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField) to Parent Model, so in Child Model the fields(in your case `email`) from Parent does not exist(Database wise). So in this approach, you can't make email field **not null**.

So its better to declare a base abstract class. Then subclass both `Person` and `User` model from there. For example:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, )
    identification = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True, default=None)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Person(Base):    

     def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class User(Base):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=60)  # <-- Override the base email field

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override field properties.
Keep Person `email` field as usual.
Change User `email` field by

```
email = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `class Meta:  abstract = True` (Note: and don't use `null` in character field, use `blank` instead.)::
ie:

```
class Human(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, )
    identification = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Person(Human):    
    def __str__():
        return self.name

class User(Human):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=60 ) #<~~~~ Email CAN'T be null
```